# Regex to C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I found a regular expressions that would find:

```
bb:hhhh="blajkeh32;,,;sekj;f!!!;"
```

that would also find:

```
bb:hhhh="blfsefsefsajkehsdfsdfse32;,,efsefesekj;f!!!;"
```

where:

```
bb:hhhh=""
```

is constant.

I used this:

```
bb\:hhhh:b*=:b*\"[^\"]*\"
```

But, now, I want to write this in C# for a System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace function call, and I don't know how to convert this regex to a string that will work in c#.

I've tried the following in C#:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(filePath1), @"dc\:source:b*=:b*""[^""]*""", ""));
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to escape any of those characters.

Comment: Could you please show us the C# code that did not work?

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(filePath1), @"dc\:source:b*=:b*""[^""]*""", "")

Comment: You can [edit] your question :-)

Comment: Then, Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the regex matching anything from bb:hhhh=" till "

```
var resultString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(subjectString, "bb:hhhh=\"[^\"]*\"").Value;
```

Comment: This did it. Wow, I made it way to complicated :o. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should accept the answer then so other users can also benefit from the question + answer

Comment: Note: Might want `*` instead of `+` if `bb:hhhh=""` is to be matched.

Comment: I had to wait 5 minutes, it told me.